# FlipClock days countdown slider for only days number?

Tags: jquery, flipclock

I am trying to countdown from 60 days to 55 days using [flipclock.js](http://flipclockjs.com/). When the page loaded it should start at 60 and stop at 55. If i see same thing tomorrow it should end at 54 days. Like that how to countdown using FlipClock